# Check if Laravel sanctum token is valid in Nextjs middelware to protect route

Tags: reactjs, laravel, api, next.js, token

I want to create auth system in Nextjs with Laravel sanctum. I have faced problem to check if token is valid or no.
Here my code in Nextjs middelaware, he is only check if token exist. so anyone can create token manualy in browser and will be redirect to dashboard.

I'dont know if this method its safe? or it's not good btw or if there is another way.
 Thank you for your help
**Middelware.ts**

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

function getToken(req: NextRequest): string | undefined {
  const { cookies } = req
  return cookies.get('token')
}
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {

const token = getToken(request)

if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/dashboard') && !token) {
  return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/', request.url))
}

if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/login') && token) {
  return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/dashboard', request.url))
}

  }
```

**Login.js**:

```
  import {useState} from 'react';
  import axios from 'axios';
  import { setCookie } from 'cookies-next';
  import {useRouter} from 'next/router'

  export default function Login ()  {
  const router = useRouter()
  let [ email, setEmail ] = useState('');
  let [ password, setPassword ] = useState('');
const  handleSubmit = async (e) =>{
  e.preventDefault();

    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie')
  .then(response => {
    axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login', {
          email: email,
          password: password
      }).then(response => {
          setCookie('token', response.data.token);
          router.push("/dashboard");
      })

  }); 
}
```

**Logincontroller** :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Handle an authentication attempt.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

    if (!$user || !Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => ['The provided credentials are incorrect.'],
        ]);
    }

    $token = $user->createToken('mytoken')->plainTextToken;
    $response = [
        'token' => $token,
        'token_type' => 'Bearer',
        'user' => $user,
    ];

    return $response;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `auth:sanctum` middleware in your route.

```php
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

Details: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#protecting-routes